# word/phrase request meaning the areas affected by making a particular change

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In a company I used to work for, whenever we made changes in a design, no matter how small, we had to fill out a form that had a field titled *effectivity* which would outline which parts of the project were affected by those changes, so we could determine which tests would have to be repeated.

But I looked up *effectivity* in several online dictionaries ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/effectivity), [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/effectivity), [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effectivity)) and they all refer to *effective* with no additional connotations in line with how my former company was using it.

Is there a word or phrase meaning the areas affected by making a particular change?

Comment: For a nice short phrase, I'd probably go with "affected areas".  :-)

Comment: Is there a problem with _areas affected_?

Comment: oh. duh. Yeah, those are both good suggestions.

Comment: purview - the scope of the influence or concerns of something. https://www.google.com/search?q=define+purview&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+purview&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7309j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

**Area of effects** would describe the areas of the project affected by the changes.

The only definition of the phrase I could find is from role playing games but it has similar meaning.

> Area of effect (often referred to as AoE) refers to a specified area in which multiple enemies can be affected ([source](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Area_of_effect))

In your context I'd define it to as:

> Area of effects (often referred to as AoE) refers to the specific areas of a project which can be affected.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the phrase "concomitant effects". 
If you look up the phrase online, it finds use in technical fields.

I like it because it highlights the secondary nature of the effects so as to differentiate from the main change.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/concomitant?s=t